# Fix stuttering audio

Tags: audio, broken

I have a long piece of recorded audio which has many regular gaps of silence:
[image]

When you zoom in you can see it like this:
[image]

Is there any way of removing these regular gaps of silence? They are around "0:00.085" long and the useable sections of audio between them are "0:00.042" long (so half as long as the silent gabs).

Ive tried using the "remove silence" with these settings:
[image]

But this only halves the silent gaps and does not fix the issue. I cannot lower the "for more than" below 10ms, but i think i need something more in the range of <1ms.

Here is a link to the file in case you want to take a look: https://we.tl/t-cioRKMzDaY

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been working with a file that is like this, and what I found was the truncate silence effect in Audacity. It allows you to enter any time value that you want. You'd still have to go in manually to do this, but at least sections would be easier.